# Add new MCE button for toggle specific cell background color

Tags: tinymce, table, buttons

I'm using tables as a calendar for free dates in my schedule.

You can see free dates here.
http://www.zachrannastanicelipec.cz/smysly-terminy/

Now I'm using the Table->Cell->Cell Properties->Advanced->background

I want to have a button (or two) for turn on/off the green background in the selected cell.

Is it possible?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: See [TinyMCE Custom Styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles).

Comment: Thank you. But this is probably too complicated for me. Is it possible to get something more straightforward please?

Comment: This is not the right place to hire a developer. Read the rules before post

Comment: Ok. I thought there would be some not complicated solution. And maybe someone had the same problem. Thank you for your advice. I didn't want to get the exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great tutorial about making a custom button to the tinymce.
http://qnimate.com/adding-buttons-to-wordpress-visual-editor/

You can just follow this guide and copy all of it. Don't forget to activate your new plugin in the plugin menu (in admin panel).

Then you can just change the code inside index.js and especially in the

`ed.addCommand("green_command", function() {`

For making the background of the selected cell toggle (on/off) you just change the code like this:

`//button functionality.
            ed.addCommand("green_command", function() {
              ed.formatter.register('termin_format', {
                 selector: 'td',
                 styles: { backgroundColor: '#adf2a7'},
               });
               ed.formatter.toggle('termin_format');`

```
        });
```